# "an example (how) to do something" or "an example about doing something"?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, prepositions

```
I will give you an example to write a CV.
```

or

```
I will give you an example how to write a CV.
```

or

```
I will give you an example about how to write a CV.
```

or

```
I will give you an example about writing a CV.
```

Which one of the above is right? If none, please, give me the correct one.

Comment: I will give you an example ***for*** / ***of*** writing a CV.

Comment: *Example of xxx* is standard phrasing. *Example about* sounds bad to me, and is [virtually unknown](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=example+of%2Cexample+about&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) in writing.

Answer (score 5):

'I will give you an example of how to write a CV'.

Comment: To be honest, this seems to be just the best of a bad bunch. The example isn't actually going to be an instance of *how to write a CV* - whatever that means (one instance out of several "CV-writing guides", perhaps?). It's simply an **example [of a] CV**.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I know. What is really needed is something like 'If you'd like to see what an impressive CV looks like, here's an example.'

Comment: @BarrieEngland: Right.  Or keep it simple: "I will teach you how to write a good CV" or "I will give you many examples of good CVs."

Comment: Is this correct? __I will give you an example **on** how to write a CV__

Comment: @Meysam: It is not what a native speaker would say.

Comment: @Julia Thank you for your suggestions, but I was really interested in "the best of a bad bunch", as FumbleFingers said. Generally, it's always possible to say things correctly in another way, but in my questions (this one and future ones that I'll ask here) I rarely seek for a different variation, rather I try to find the correct way, if there is such, as close as possible to the original phrase in the question.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of tutorials about how to do something but none for doing something, hence

```
I will give you an example of how to write a CV.
```

Answer (score 0):

> I will give you an example to write a CV.

This means that I will use the example to write a CV. Like "I will give you a pen to write a CV." It's awkward. It leaves the listener wondering what exactly you're going to give them.

> I will give you an example how to write a CV.

This is missing a connector. What is the relationship between the example and how to write a CV?

> I will give you an example about how to write a CV.

It's hard to make any sense of this. An "example" must be an instance of the thing it is an example of. So if this is in fact an example about how to write a CV, what would it be? A CV is not about how to write a CV. But nothing other than a CV is an example of a CV. So what could this be describing?

I could see one way this could be used.

Jack: I'm writing a book about how to write a CV. Do you have any examples of such books?

Jill: I will give you an example about how to write a CV.

It's awkward, but not incorrect (assuming the thing you're talking about is in fact about how to write a CV).

> I will give you an example about writing a CV.

Same problem as above. What would be an example about writing a CV? A CV is not about writing a CV. And only a CV is an example of a CV.